# Pointers and recurency - I'm trying to save memory

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, recurrence

I'm trying to write program that create squere for string. Squere has to be larger then string.length(). If there is word 'C++' I need 2x2 array to fill it inside.
So I  have written code

```
 #include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int pole(int &a,const int* l);
int main(){
    string code;
    cin >> code;
    int wall=1;
    pole(wall,code.length());
    cout << wall;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
int pole(int &a,const int* l){
    if (a*a > l) return a;
    else {
    a+=1;
    pole(a,l);
    }
}
```

I bet that using pointer with recunrency save a lot of memory but I can't compile it. I'm trying to understand compilers error but is 2 hard for me ;/

Here is compiler list of errors

```
> in main() 
11 25 Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int (*)(int&, const int*)' 
 6 5> [Error] in passing argument 1 of 'int pole(int&, const int*)' 
 in pole() 17 12 
>[Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and
> integer [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: You try to pass a variable called 'pole' that was never declared as the first parameter to your pole function.

Comment: I put wrong code inside question. Fixed it!

Comment: `code.length()` isn't an pointer, and likely  not an `int` either. Using pointers isn't going to "save" any memory anyway. On a 64-bit system `int` is 4 bytes and `int*` is 8 bytes. Not a great saving!

Comment: but there is poitner for recurency function so... it doesnt make copy for each function used, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
pole(pole, code.length());
```

You are passing as the second variable the result of `length()`, which is of type `std::string::size_type`, which the function `pole` accepts a pointer to `int`. Those two types are incompatible.

The second problem is that one branch of your `if` statement inside `pole` does not contain a `return` statement, thus giving your program Undefined Behavior.

You may want to change your function `pole` this way:

```
int pole(int &a, std::string::size_type l) {
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               Also, passing by reference is unnecessary here

    if (a*a > static_cast<int>(l)) return a;
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//            Just to communicate that you are aware of the
//            signed-to-unsigned comparison here
    else {
    a+=1;
    return pole(a,l);
//  ^^^^^^
//  Do not forget this, or your program will have Undefined Behavior!
    }
}
```

[Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4cvdpz%2445) you can see your modified program compile and run.

Comment: I'm still confused about code. I see it works but still - does it make a copy of l for each function used? When I use refence for a I know that there isn't copy for a

Comment: Found that this algoritm is much shorter

 #include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void pole(int &a, string::size_type l);
int main(){
    string code;
    cin >> code;
    int wall=1;
    pole(wall,code.length());
    cout << wall;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void pole(int &a, std::string::size_type l){
    if (a*a < static_cast<int>(l))
    pole(a+=1,l);
}

Comment: @FilipBartuzi: Yes, it passes by value, but this is not a problem, since `std::string::size_type` is an unsigned integral value, which is cheap to copy. Since copying is fast, and you do not need to modify `l` inside `pole`, there is no reason why to pass by reference, or to pass a pointer. Moreover, passing a pointer of a temporary return value (like you were doing) is illegal. You should have first stored it in a variable, and then passed the address of that variable, but again, there is no reason to do this. Just pass by value. It could even be more efficient than passing pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an [unsigned integer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) (coming from `std::string::length`) as a pointer in:

```
pole(wall,code.length());
```

Change your pole declarations to:

```
int pole(int a, int l);
```

Saving memory on `int` is just nonsense there. Pointers are sometimes even more memory expensive than simple integers.

You should learn to save memory with huge objects instead.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought that 'code'  pole(wall,(void *)code.length()); 'code' will work but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
int pole(int &a,const int* l){
    if (a*a > l) return a;
    else {
    a+=1;
    pole(a,l);
    }
}
```

first, you cannot initialize `int* l` with `size_t` argument.
Also you do later comparison between address, not value pointed too.
Is this what you wanted?